# How is the weights_init parameter used in scikit-learn's GaussianMixture clustering algorithm?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

**The Question Up Front:** How do I use the `weights_init` parameter in `sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture` (GMM) to initialize GMM from the outputs of K-Means performed by a separate python package?

**Objectives:**

1. Perform K-Means clustering on a large dataset on a GPU cluster using the RAPIDS CUML library.
2. Initialize `GaussianMixture` using output of objective 1.


   **Requirement**: Ensure that pairing the external K-Means algorithm and scikit-learn's GMM results in the same behavior as the default GMM initialization method.

The default implementation of GMM is as follows:

```
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=K, init_params='kmeans')
```

**The Issue:** After reading through the docs, examining source code, and looking for other custom implementations, I am still a little unsure regarding my approach, specifically regarding the use of the input parameters `weights_init`.  My proposed approach follows:

```
from cuml import KMeans
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

# KMeans performed on GPU cluster w/ CUML library:
km = KMeans(n_clusters=K)
km.fit_predict(data)
labels = km.labels_
centroids = km.cluster_centers_

# GMM performed on CPU w/ sklearn library:
gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=K, means_init=centroids, weights_init=???)
labels = gmm.fit_predict(data)
centroids = gmm.means_
```

I can think of a couple ways to determine the `weights_init`, but I'm after the way used in the default implementation.  My intuition suggests that the weights are simply the fraction of samples in the dataset that belong to a particular cluster, but I can't find anything to confirm this.  Thanks ahead of time for any help or clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code to use cuML's KMeans to create the weights for sklearn's GaussianMixture in place of the default weights is provided below.
You need to use the the labels obtained from cuML's KMeans model to create the weights.
I have used the `make_blobs` dataset in the example below:

```
import numpy as np
from cuml.cluster import KMeans as cuKMeans

from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans as skKMeans
from sklearn.metrics import adjusted_rand_score
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
from sklearn.mixture._gaussian_mixture import _estimate_gaussian_parameters

n_samples = 100
n_features = 2

n_clusters = 5
random_state = 0

data, labels = make_blobs(n_samples=n_samples,
                          n_features=n_features,
                          centers=n_clusters,
                          random_state=random_state,
                          cluster_std=0.1)
km = cuKMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, n_init=1)
km.fit(data)
label = km.labels_
centroids = km.cluster_centers_

# calculate the weights
resp = np.zeros((n_samples, n_clusters))
resp[np.arange(n_samples), label] = 1

weights, _, _ = _estimate_gaussian_parameters(data, resp, reg_covar=1e-6, covariance_type='full')
weights /= n_samples
print("weights : ", weights)

gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=n_clusters, means_init=centroids, weights_init=weights)
labels = gmm.fit_predict(data)
gmm_centroids = gmm.means_
print(" gmm_centroids values with cuml weights : ")
print(gmm_centroids)

# default GM without cuml kmeans

default_gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=n_clusters, means_init=centroids, weights_init=weights)
labels = default_gmm.fit_predict(data)
default_gmm_centroids = default_gmm.means_
print("gmm_centroids values with default weights : ")
print(default_gmm_centroids)
```